# How to encode from PCM to AAC Format within a .mpg container?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to encode a file which has PCM audio to AAC format within a .mpg container.

This file has 1 Audio stream with 8 Channels. When I tried to encode with below code I am getting silence audio.

Tried audio manipulation like amerge split but no luck.

`ffmpeg8 -ss 00:00:00.000 -t 00:00:18.000 -i input1 -ss 00:00:18.001 -t 00:00:35.000 -i input2 -filter_complex "[0:v:0]crop=out_h=576:y=32,yadif=1:-1:0[part1crop]; [1:v:0]crop=out_h=576:y=32,yadif=1:-1:0[part2crop]; [part1crop][0:a:0][part2crop][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[vconcat][aconcat]" -map '[vconcat]' -codec:v libx264 -profile:v High -level 4.1 -coder 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -video_track_timescale 25 -r 25 -s:v 1024x576 -aspect 16:9  -x264-params "cabac=0:ref=3:weightp=2:keyint=50:keyint_min=5:bframes=0:b-adapt=0:subq=6:subme=7:nal-hrd=cbr:cbv_maxrate=22500:cbv-bufsize=30000" -map '[aconcat]' -codec:a libfdk_aac  -ar 48000 -ac 2 -b:a 192K -write_tmcd off /output.mpg`

Tried with mp2 codec it works perfectly. This problem occurs only when I use AAC codec.

Input Audio properties:

```
Audio
ID                                       : 3
Format                                   : PCM
Format settings, wrapping mode           : Frame (D-10)
Codec ID                                 : 0D01030102010101
Duration                                 : 35 s 0 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 9 216 kb/s
Encoded bit rate                         : 12.3 Mb/s
Channel(s)                               : 8 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L C R, Side: L R, Back: L R, LFE
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS (1920 SPF)
Bit depth                                : 24 bits
Stream size                              : 38.5 MiB (15%)
Encoded stream size                      : 51.3 MiB (20%)
Title                                    : A1
Locked                                   : Yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsupported audio codec for mpeg. Must be:

- mp1
- mp2
- mp3
- 16-bit pcm_dvd
- pcm_s16be
- ac3
- dts

pcm_dvd and pcm_s16be will be the only two that support 8 channel layout.

Or use a different output container format such as `.ts`.